# Microsoft Access: using passwords to set different permission levels

Tags: ms-access

I am a teaching an IT course to 15 year-olds.  Part of the course is an assignment in which we create basic relational databases using Access.  I have a beginners level knowledge of Access (it is not my background) and the students are not expected to use VBA (it is far beyond the scope of what we cover in the course).

The examining body has asked the following:
The database will have a table with some basic student data (name, age, exam score etc).  We will create a form to view/edit/add etc.  But we are then asked to implement some functionality so that one password ("password1") only grants Read-Only access to the system but a second password ("password2") grants full editing rights.

I have seen some very complex solutions to this online, but nothing that is appropriate for the level of students this course is aimed at.

As this is an educational setting we don't need to be overly concerned with the actual integrity of the system (it's just a basic course) and VBA is not an option.

Is there an option that will allow us to have a login screen that takes users that enter one password to a Form with editing options disabled, and if the other password entered they are enabled (and I just hide the table from view... remember this is basic)?

Thanks, sorry for such a basic question... bear in mind this course is being discontinued in 2023 ;)

Comment: The 'option' would be a form and code (VBA or macro) you build. This needs an If Then conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using VBA I assume that you are using macros to open forms, etc.

You can open a form in read-only mode with the action `OpenForm` by setting the `Data Mode` to `Read Only`.

If you want to disable buttons in the form you just opened, you can execute the action `SetValue` with `Item` = `[Forms]![frmSelect]![cmdSelect].[Enabled]` or `Item` = `[Screen].[ActiveForm]![cmdSelect].[Enabled]` and `Expression` = `False`. (I assume that the form name is `frmSelect` and the button name `cmdSelect`.)

The VBA equivalent would be:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSelect", DataMode:=acFormReadOnly
Forms!frmSelect!cmdSelect.Enabled = False
```

---

In older Access Versions (< 2007) a completely different way is to use the built-in security system (which I don't like). See: [How To Manage User Permissions In Access Database?](https://www.accessrepairnrecovery.com/blog/manage-user-permissions-in-access-database)

Comment: I think that link is referring to Access 2003 and older versions.

Comment: @June7, yes. See [What happened to user-level security?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-happened-to-user-level-security-69b362cd-503f-4e8a-a735-fb923ffb9fa3).